# Exception handing in low level library functions

Tags: c#, dll, exception

We are writing a low level library of functions (mostly emulating some Matlab sig processing functions) - basically a set of static methods on a a static object.  This will then be consumed in a higher level framework (which we are writting too).  The framework and low level library are both for internal use (not public).

**What is a good exception handling model for this case?**  Two options I see are:
1. No exception handling in the low level lib - let division by zero etc exceptions just bubble up and handle them in the consuming framework.
2. In each of the low level functions systematically check arguments for values that might produce overflow, division by zero, unexpect root of -ve num etc and throw ArgumentException with diagnostic text about issue.

Does 2. offer advantage over 1. that justifies the additional code?  My feeling is this might make location of where issues are occuring easier.
**Is there a argument for doing one or the other?**

Comment: 2. can be quite important to help a programmer use your library.  Good exceptions are extremely useful when such a programmer doesn't know the library well enough.  And you avoided a "your code sucks" support call, not the kind you ever want to get.  It is *not* a substitute for 1, you are pretty unlikely to cover every possible failure and the cost of the checking may be prohibitive in some cases.  Both 1 and 2 apply.

Comment: Thats a pretty decent answer for a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends a great deal on the library in question:

- Is it going to be used exclusively by your oragnisation, or will it be distributed publicly?
- Are there any security implications?
- What would be the business cost of it failing?

In general, it is good practice to perform parameter validation on 'public'* APIs.  What you do in the event of a failure is up to you, but throwing an ArgumentException with an informative text description is a good idea and helpful to the developer using your library.

There are many resources that discuss the topic in various scenarios including a similar question on Programmers: [Should a method validate its parameters?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/64926/131576).  Ignore that it is marked as a duplicate - it isn't really.

If the library is to be opened to the general public, not validating parameters can lead to all kinds of security vulnerabilities, as things like not bound checking arrays and not validation pointers can lead to malicious code being injected in the most unexpected ways and places!

Microsoft have a few things to say on the subject regarding their CRT library functions: [Parameter Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx).

My (personal) recommendation would be to go for option 2: validate your parameters and throw meaningful exceptions.

*The meaning of 'public' is open to interpretation.

Comment: That linked question is interesting - the top 2 answers are pretty much oposing yet they hava a similar number of votes (16:13) - seems its not clear cut and as you say depends on context.

Comment: @Ricibob Since you're 'emulating' Matlab functions, you should probably include the way Matlab handles bounds checking [Exception Handling in a MATLAB Application](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/error-reporting-in-a-matlab-application.html).  (I'm being a bit pedantic about the definition of emulation here.)